# What is the difference between with or without legato in singing?

Tags: technique, voice, classical-music, articulation, opera

In singing specially classic music, what is the difference between when the legato is written and when it's not they all sound the same connected line?

Comment: I would not assume that a lack of legato phrasing marks imply staccato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of legato is to run one note into the next, without separation between them. Usually in singing this occurs most prominently in 'melismas' which are points when a single syllable is sung across multiple notes.

While there has to be some separation between syllables, you can still sing in a legato way, in which the gap between notes is reduced, and you sing in a flowing, joined-up way.

If it helps, the opposite is staccato, where the start of each note is emphasized and there's almost a gap for a breath between each note. Legato is as flowing and smooth a way as possible.

There's a bit of a more standard answer in the wikipedia page for legato (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legato):

> In classical singing, legato means a string of sustained vowels with minimal interruption from consonants.

It also notes that for classical singing, legato is a default state, if you're not told to emphasize the attack part of notes, you run phrases together.

> In Western Classical vocal music, singers generally use it on any phrase without explicit articulation marks

Comment: so does that give the singer the free to cut through a phrase without slur to breath for example or make an impression specially in opera? and thanks a lot

Comment: As a rule, try to breathe between phrases. Breathe deeply and portion the breath out to get through it (this improves with practise). If you need to break up a phrase, look for low-impact points to take a short "snatch breath"